# How to Draw a shape or bitmap into another Bitmap , Java/android

Tags: java, android, canvas

I want to draw a shape(many circles particularly) into a Specific Bitmap.
I have never used canvas / 2D graphs etc.
Anyone that can point me to the right direction to do what i want.?

### #

As i see it i create a Drawable put the bitmap in it then "canvas-it" to the shapes i want etc
but i really need some guideline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK i sorted it out

```
Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(CON.getResources(),R.drawable.deltio);
Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), b.getConfig());
canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawBitmap(b, new Matrix(), null);
canvas.drawCircle(750, 14, 11, paint);
```

Comment: What are you doing with the resulting canvas to show the image in your UI?

Comment: Bitmap b;
b.setImageBitmap(bmOverlay);